# Generic function to print any vector in reverse, compiler error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdvector

Right now I'm learning templates and vectors. I made a simple function to print a vector having elements of any data type from the `.back()` element to the `.front()` element.

```
template <typename Type>
void printVectorReverse(const vector<Type>& stuff)
{
    for (auto it = stuff.crbegin(); it != crend(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm compiling the program, and I got an error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 template_functions.cpp 
template_functions.cpp: In function ‘void printVectorReverse(const std::vector<Type>&)’:
template_functions.cpp:66:49: error: there are no arguments to ‘crend’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘crend’ must be available [-fpermissive]
     for (auto it = stuff.crbegin(); it != crend(); ++it) {
                                                 ^
template_functions.cpp:66:49: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

I see no syntax errors here. There is a template typename declaration above the function.  The vector is `const` pass by reference to avoid copying it, and so the function would not inadvertently change the vector. I have a constant reverse iterator pointing to the `.back()` element. Then I dereference the iterator and increment it until it reaches the reverse end of the vector and **falls of the end**. I am using `auto` because the vector can have any data type.

How do I read this error by the way? What does this mean? Please don't be so harsh as this is a relatively new topic for me. I really want to learn templates and sequence containers.

Comment: The error is saying that it can't find a `crend` function to call.

Comment: `stuff.crend()`.

Comment: The sentence you are looking for is *"a declaration of 'crend' must be available"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is read like so:

> error: there are no arguments to ‘crend’ that depend on a template parameter, **so a** [function] **declaration of ‘crend’ must be available** [-fpermissive]

This means the compiler doesn't know what `crend()` is. It suspects it's a function, but can't find a declaration of it.

You've made a typo; you need to have `stuff.crend()`:

```
for (auto it = stuff.crbegin(); it != stuff.crend(); ++it)
```

Comment: That's it, I've made a typo! So it thinks that `crend()` is a standalone function, and of course it can't find the apporpriate declaration for it.